# Issue with converting template specializations in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I want to convert my LIFO template specialization to a FIFO template specialization with the `=()` operator. I tried figuring out what the problem could be, but I keep getting the same errors.

In LFO.h i have 2 template specializations of LFO, one for LIFO and one for FIFO. The goal is to convert the LIFO one to the FIFO and reverse. I want to do this to finally compare the 2 objects with the `==()` operator. I'm getting an error on the conversion and an error on the comparision.

My code:

**LFO.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

enum enumBehavior { LIFO, FIFO };

template<typename DateType, enumBehavior Behavior, int MaxElements> class LFO {

};

template<int MaxElements> class LFO<string, LIFO, MaxElements> {
protected:
    vector<string> vector;
public:
    void Push(string elem) {
        if ((int)vector.size() < MaxElements) {
            vector.push_back(elem);
        }
        else
            cout << "LIFO full - couldn't push element\n";
    }
    bool Pop() {
        vector.clear();
    }
    const string Top() const {
        string returnString = "";
        for (int i = (int)vector.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            returnString += vector[i];
        }
        return returnString;
    }
    bool isEmpty() const {
        return (int)vector.size() <= 0 ? true : false;
    }
    bool isFull() const {
        return (int)vector.size() >= MaxElements ? true : false;
    }
    bool operator==(const LFO<string, LIFO, MaxElements>& listToAppend) {
        LFO list(listToAppend);
        return this->Top() == list.Top();
    }
    LFO<string, LIFO, MaxElements>& operator=(const LFO<string, FIFO, MaxElements>& other) {
        LFO<string, FIFO, MaxElements> list(other);
        this->Pop();
        this->Push(list.Top());
        return *this;
    }
};

template<int MaxElements> class LFO<string, FIFO, MaxElements> {
protected:
    vector<string> vector;
public:
    void Push(string elem) {
        if ((int)vector.size() < MaxElements) {
            vector.push_back(elem);
        }
        else
            cout << "FIFO full - couldn't push element\n";
    }
    bool Pop() {
        vector.clear();
    }
    const string Top() const {
        string returnString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < (int)vector.size(); i++) {
            returnString += vector[i];
        }
        return returnString;
    }
    bool isEmpty() const {
        return (int)vector.size() <= 0 ? true : false;
    }
    bool isFull() const {
        return (int)vector.size() >= MaxElements ? true : false;
    }
    bool operator==(const LFO<string, FIFO, MaxElements>& listToAppend) {
        LFO list(listToAppend);
        return this->Top() == list.Top();
    }
    LFO<string, FIFO, MaxElements>& operator=(const LFO<string, LIFO, MaxElements>& other) {
        LFO<string, LIFO, MaxElements> list(other);
        this->Pop();
        this->Push(list.Top());
        return *this;
    }
};
```

**StringLifo.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "LFO.h"

template<int maxElements> class StringLIFO:
    public LFO<string, LIFO, maxElements>
{
public:
    bool Palindrome(const LFO<string, FIFO, maxElements>& input) {
        LFO<string, LIFO, maxElements>& lfo = input;                   //Error 1
        bool equal = this == lfo;                                      //Error 2
        return equal;
    }
};
```

I keep getting this errors:

```
Error   C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'const LFO<std::string,FIFO,30>' to 'LFO<std::string,LIFO,30> &'    Palindrome  C:\Users\J\source\repos\Palindrome\Palindrome\StringLIFO.h  16  

Error   C2679   binary '==': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'LFO<std::string,LIFO,30>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)   Palindrome  C:\Users\J\source\repos\Palindrome\Palindrome\StringLIFO.h  17
```

I wonder what's wrong with my code?

---

## **EDIT**

By updating the function `Palindrome()` in `StringLIFO.h` I still get one error.

```
bool Palindrome(const LFO<string, FIFO, maxElements>& input) {
        const LFO<string, LIFO, maxElements>& lfo = input;
        return (*this == lfo);
    }
```

The error now is:

```
binary '=': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const LFO<std::string,LIFO,30>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Maybe the output can be usefull:

```
1>C:\Users\J\source\repos\Palindrome\Palindrome\StringLIFO.h(16,1): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'const LFO<std::string,FIFO,30>' to 'const LFO<std::string,LIFO,30> &'
1>C:\Users\J\source\repos\Palindrome\Palindrome\StringLIFO.h(16,1): message : Reason: cannot convert from 'const LFO<std::string,FIFO,30>' to 'const LFO<std::string,LIFO,30>'
1>C:\Users\J\source\repos\Palindrome\Palindrome\StringLIFO.h(16,8): message : No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>C:\Users\J\source\repos\Palindrome\Palindrome\StringLIFO.h(15): message : while compiling class template member function 'bool StringLIFO<30>::Palindrome(const LFO<std::string,FIFO,30> &)'
1>C:\Users\J\source\repos\Palindrome\Palindrome\Palindrome.cpp(845): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool StringLIFO<30>::Palindrome(const LFO<std::string,FIFO,30> &)' being compiled
1>C:\Users\J\source\repos\Palindrome\Palindrome\Palindrome.cpp(801): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'StringLIFO<30>' being compiled
```

Comment: does your class provide `operator==` ?

Comment: In the first error you are trying to create a non-const reference from a const reference. I guess you just wanted  `LFO<string, LIFO, maxElements> lfo = input;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it myself bij replacing the function `Palindrome()` with:

```
bool Palindrome(LFO<string, FIFO, maxElements>& input) {
    LFO<string, LIFO, maxElements> lfo;
    lfo.operator=(input);
    return this->operator==(lfo);
}
```

And guess what?? It works!

Answer (score 0):

First error is because of missing `const`: you try to assign a const reference to non-const reference

```
const LFO<string, LIFO, maxElements>& lfo = input; 
^~~~~
```

Second is due to fact that you are trying to compare a pointer `this` to a reference to `LFO` object. It seems that you wanted to dereference `this`. I suggest using parantheses when multiple operands are involved, even if it is okay without them:

```
bool equal = (*this == lfo); 
              ^
```

---

Shorter version:

```
bool Palindrome(const LFO<string, FIFO, maxElements>& input) {
    return *this == input;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The first error is solved! Still I have this error: `cannot convert from 'const LFO<std::string,FIFO,30>' to 'const LFO<std::string,LIFO,30> &'
` .

Comment: I was wondering why this error occures. I am passing a const reference as expected in the `=()` operator.

Comment: @Jordy That's a strange one. There isn't any real difference between `const LFO<std::string,FIFO,30>` and `const LFO<std::string,FIFO,30> &` when you want to convert one to another.